# Copy XML array from one XML Object to another xml Object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

how to copy one xml object values from one xml object to another empty xml object.

I have one xml object from the xml array and need to copy that to another xml object.
How can i copy xml from one object to another

if am parsing the **XML object** with **for loop** and i get the nodes

```
var myXML:xml = new xml();
for(...)
if(xmlObj.product[i].name == 'myproduct'){
  /// copy this to 'myXML' xml object .. how??


}

trace(myXML)
```

Comment: are you using as3 or as2? your question is tagged with both, but this specific operation is quite different between the two.

Comment: im asking about the as3 script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would probably do this, using AS3's E4X capabilities.

```
private function copyMyProductXMLNodes():void
{
    var xmlObj:XML = <productList><product name="notMyProduct">product 1</product><product name="myProduct">product 2</product><product name="notMyProduct">product 3</product><product name="myProduct">product 4</product></productList>;
    var myXML:XML = <myProductList></myProductList>;

    for each(var productItem:XML in xmlObj.product)
    {
        if(productItem.@name == 'myProduct')
        {
            myXML.appendChild(productItem.copy());
        }
    }

    trace(myXML.toXMLString())
}
```

I instantiated the myXML var with an XML literal, rather than leaving it as new XML() because the appendChild method can't append anything to an XML object until it has a top-level node.

I'd be glad to add a little more commentary on this code, if that would be helpful.  Just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

try something like:

```
var newXml:XML = new XML(oldXml.toXMLString());
```

Comment: how to copy the specific childs only.

Comment: then use var newXml:XML = new XML(xmlObj.product[i]);

Comment: this will only work if the xml is a single element (eg one root tag) otherwise you need to start using xmlList objects, see http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/using_xml_as3_pg1.htm

Comment: to clarify the preceding comment, it doesn't have to contain ONLY a single element, but there must only be 1 element at the root. meaning, <foo><bar/><bar/><bar/></foo> is working as expected.